# How to remove header from AJAX call for a single request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, backbone.js

I'm building an app, using Rails and Backbone as my back-end, that requires users to login to access certain pages. On one of the user authenticated pages, I have it setup so they can create an entry in my database, by entering in data, which is then sent to the Google Maps API to retrieve the latitude and longitude.

Via a helper function, I'm checking if the user is authenticated or not, but when I send up the AJAX call to Google Maps API, the user token is also being sent up. Here's the code that I have set up right now.

In my api js file, which is ran first on load for my page

```
var token = $('#api-token').val();
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers:{
    "accept": "application/json",
    "token": token
  }
});
```

In my users_controller.rb

```
def profile
    authorize!
    @user = current_user
    @bathrooms = Bathroom.all.sort_by { |name| name }
    render layout: 'profile_layout'
end


def authorize!
  redirect_to '/login' unless current_user
end

def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
```

Here's my AJAX call

```
 function getInfo(location) {
  console.log('getInfo');
  $.ajax({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
    data:{address: location, key: 'API KEY GOES HERE'},
    success: function(data) {
      extractData(data);
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try following steps:

```
function getInfo(location) {
  console.log('getInfo');

  delete $.ajaxSettings.headers["token"]; // Remove header before call

  $.ajax({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
    data:{address: location, key: 'API KEY GOES HERE'},
    success: function(data) {
      extractData(data);
    }
  });

  $.ajaxSettings.headers["token"] = token; // Add it back immediately
}
```

Comment: or modify ajax call to synchronous or put back the token in succes function otherwise it can happen that the token can be putted back before the ajax call

Comment: @Matzy, thanks for your comment. But token will not be picked up for above Ajax call. As soon as above `$.ajax({}}` block gets executed by javascript engine; the XHR request will get created. At that time "token" will not be there in `$.ajaxSettings`. Hence no matter at which point later above Ajax request get fired it will not have "token" within it.

Comment: This worked for me. I just had to store the token in a local variable within the function, just to make sure that I was able to put it back into the ajaxSettings.headers. I didn't know how to access the token, after initializing it, so I was lost for the past half week. @vijayP Thanks!!

Comment: My pleasure jdlam..:)